# Let $K$ a operator of continued fraction.Is this true?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, continued-fractions

$\DeclareMathOperator*\K{K}$
Let $\K$ a operator of continued fraction.
Show that:
$$1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k}\varphi_4\cdots \varphi_{2k+2}=\frac{1}{1+\displaystyle\K_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{\varphi_{2k}}{1-\varphi_{2k}}}$$

What's a name of this little theorem? This theorem is true?

Comment: In other words,
$1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k}\prod_{j=2}^{k+1}a_j=\frac{1}{1+\displaystyle\K_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{a_{k}}{1-a_{k}}}
$.

Comment: Probably Euler.